# UISearchDisplayController : application is showing exception

Tags: iphone, exception, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Im trying to work with UISearchDisplay controller
the application is launching correctly. When i start typing in the UISearchbarController its showing the following exception and exiting the application.

The exception is as follows:
[BrowserViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b4ccc0
2010-08-13 11:59:58.469 MixedApplication[7297:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BrowserViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b4ccc0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your code for the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection?

EDIT: UISearchBar will not work for a UIWebView

Comment: i need to get the search result from a web view.

Comment: ok, but something in your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection is making your app crash. If you post it, we can help you.

Comment: Is it possible to connect a UISearchDisplayController to a WebView?

Comment: No, and this is where you're having troubles then. If you want to search for something in the Web View, implement a UITextField somewhere in your controller. Get the text from said UITextField and perform your search with that text.

Comment: Thank you Raphael,
I will change UISearchDispaly controller to UISearchBer
Thank your for your help